# Magento: How to change the deisgn of few particular product pages from the rest?

Tags: magento

I want to make custom changes in few product pages like changing the add to cart button ,add some text etc.I know that I can change the layout of product page from back end,I can add some blocks to the product page but how to made changes like I mentioned in Product  page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution myself.

First, create your new template files. I copied the originals, and created view-diff.phtml, and media-diff.phtml in the same directories as the originals. Once that is complete, edit a product, and go to the “Design” tab. In the “Custom Layout Update” text area, you can put the following, which will redefine which templates it uses for that product

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view-diff.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="product.info.media">
    <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view/media-diff.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Thats it!